# Call function in new window on load

Tags: javascript

Is this possible?

```
var win = window.open(url);

win.func = function() {
    win.someFunc();
    // ...
}
```

Then I want `func` to be called, when `win`'s scripts and **DOM** is fully loaded. jQuery solution will be good too.

Comment: Wouldn't that create immediate cross-site scripting issues?

Comment: You'd be injecting JavaScript to whatever window you open. That's pretty much the definition of cross-site scripting. If the target page is "yours", you don't really need this (use cookies or request parameters, or whatever else).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just use this in your html that loads with window.open.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  someFunc();
});
```

UPDATE: If you have to pass parameters than you can, as TJHeuvel stated, from ready function call function from opener window that calls someFunc.

Or you can have "global" variable, in your main window, that holds your parameters than in your someFunc() you can access it like

```
window.opener.myparameters.param1;
window.opener.myparameters.param2;
```

assuming that myparameters has param1 and pram2 fields.

UPDATE: examples

```
myparameters = new Object();
myparameters.param1 = "1";
myparameters.param2 = "2";
```

or

```
myparameters = {param1: "1", param2: "2"};
```

Comment: Oh, sorry, I forgot to note, that parent window should pass parameter to child.

Answer (score 0):

You can have the child window call a parent function onload. As such:

```
window.onload = function()
{
 window.opener.ChildLoaded(this);
}
```